# Delete row in gridview get error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to delete row in grid view , this is my backend code from rowcommand.
And i have create a OnRowDeleting but nothing in the function.

```
protected void grid2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.CommandName) // check the incoming command name
            {
case "remove":
                    if (grid2.Rows.Count > 1)
                    {
                        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                        //GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grid2.Rows[rowIndex];
                        grid2.DeleteRow(rowIndex); //error pointing to this
                        grid2.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "
<script>alert('Last row');</script>");
                        }
                        break;
    }
```

My frontend code

```
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
 CssClass="btn btn-primary" CommandName="remove" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

i get this error when i click delete button

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Deleting is not supported by data source
>   'SqlDataSource2' unless DeleteCommand is specified.

**Datasource**

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStr_epsi %>" 
                             ProviderName="<%$  ConnectionStrings:ConnStr_epsi.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**My grid**

```
 <grd:MultiSelectGridView ID="grid2" runat="server" Width="500px" 
                        CssClass="paging_gridview" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns ="false" PageSize="10" PagerType="Custom"  
                        ShowFooter="true" OnRowDeleting="grid2_RowDeleting" 
                        MultiSelectDataKeyName="Urid,Name" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                        MultiSelectColumnIndex="0" EnableMultiSelect="false" GridLines="None" BorderStyle="None"  OnRowCommand="grid2_RowCommand"
                        >
```

Comment: plz update the front end code with datasource

Comment: Google would give you solution in 1st search result itself, had you used it.

Comment: @Chandru hi, im updated

Comment: @Jan you haven't updated the grid...

Comment: @Chandru hi im just updated

Comment: Try this links http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/select-add-update-and-delete-data-in-a-Asp-Net-gridview-control/

Answer (score 0):

you have to put CommandName as "Delete" insted of "remove"
for example :

```
<asp:ButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:ButtonColumn>
```

Comment: also change in your function

Comment: changed and nothing happen

Comment: You are deleting the row from the gridview but you are then going and calling databind again which is just refreshing the gridview to the same state that the original datasource is in.

Either remove it from the datasource and then databind, or databind and remove it from the gridview without redatabinding.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion..can i have example? i cannot really understand what u mean

Comment: why you not use Gridview1_RowDeleting event ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89233/discussion-between-pranav-patel-and-jan).